# Pluggable database vs Postgresql

Tags: database, oracle, postgresql

I'm Reading abit about Oracle's PDB(pluggable databases) and what I understand is that you just have several databases(PDBs) inside one instance/machine. Therefore you save Resources, such as RAM and CPU.

But how is PDBs different compared to, for example Postgresql with many databases inside one instance ?
I mean, don't you achieve the same thing?

Comment: Yes the concepts are very similar. The difference is that Postgres was designed around this from the beginning whereas Oracle was designed around the concept of a single "database" over 30 years ago and only with 12c this has changed.

Comment: Yes, but what is the difference? I mean, why should I use PDBs when I could just create serveral dbs?

Comment: Because the overhead of an instance in Oracle is quite big. A single instance with multiple PDBs is easier to manage.

Comment: Yes, that is one advantage, but are there more advantanges?
Does the Query optimizier perform better with PDB? 
Is there a paper about this by the way?

Comment: You mean something like the [Concepts Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/cdbovrvw.htm#CNCPT89234)?

Comment: More like, a paper of PDB vs 1 instance, several dbs, where they compare them. I know that Oracle has compared PDB with VMs, but are there anymore papers about this?

Answer (score 2):

Oracle PDBs can be plug and unplug as needed, where in PostgreSQL we cannot achieve that easily. Because in PostgreSQL a database may have tables spread in different tablespaces which are independent of database.

In oracle one tablespace belongs to one pdb (or database) only, where as in PostgeSQL it is not. Similarly users also.